# Why does video sequencer change colours of images when rendered as MPEG?

Tags: rendering, color

[image: Screenshot shows shows rendered file]

I have tried changing filmic to standard - also not working.
I have fixed this already using a work around with exposure and gamma settings and the result was 'good enough'.

Interestingly in an older version of Blender (2.9 I think) the problem was resolved when creating a new file as Video Editing. As opposed to creating a new 'General' file and then clicking the Video Editing workspace tab - odd right ?!

And yes, I've only encountered this issue with Blender 3.2 recently.
The issue is common to both Sequencer and Video Editor.

Interestingly, Cycles does create accurate colours and outputs colour accurate PNG files when set to standard.